# Failed to sign CSR with the CA root key

Tags: authentication, certificates

I'm trying to implement Mutual Certificate Authentication , I have to be the CA and server at the same time , generate certificates and sign them for users. and I'm following this [tutorial](http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/) which is a very simple one comparing to the complicated articles on the web , steps are :

> - The process for creating your own certificate authority is pretty straight forward:
>
>   1. Create a private key
>   2. Self-sign
>   3. Install root CA on your various workstations // ????
> - Once you do that, every device that you manage via HTTPS just needs to have its own    certificate created with the following steps:
>
>   1. Create CSR for device
>   2. Sign CSR with root CA key /// THIS STEP

Create the Root Key :

```
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048
```

self-sign this certificate.

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
```

Create A Certificate (Done Once Per Device) :

```
openssl genrsa -out device.key 2048
openssl req -new -key device.key -out device.csr
openssl x509 -req -in device.csr -CA root.pem -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out device.crt -days 500
```

The last command is giving me this error :

```
Signature ok
subject=/C=XX/L=Default City/O=Default Company Ltd/CN=192.168.1.108
Error opening CA Certificate root.pem
3078969068:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:355:fopen('root.pem','r')
3078969068:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:357:
unable to load certificate
```

The root.pem exists in the same folder why is it not being seen ?

Also, the first two commands gave me two files, `root.key` and `root.pem`:
there's no `crt` file to give to browser .

What's wrong?

Comment: `openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
    ...
    openssl x509 -req -in device.csr -CA root.pem -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out device.crt -days 500`

Is your certificate `root.pem` or `rootCA.pem`?

Comment: yes , you are right , i was copying from the page . :$ 
I got the device.crt now , import it to firefox , but when asking for ip of the server with https , it gave me that page woth yellow sign "Untrusted Connection" !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the name of your certificate. It's inconsistent (`root.pem` in a command, `rootCA.pem` in another).

You can install the `root.pem` file on your client hosts as indicated in the article, it's your CA certificate. `PEM` is a format for certificate, others exist. `.crt` is a generic extension. You can rename your certificate from `root.pem` to `root.crt` if you want to.

Comment: so I have to give the browser the root.pem (after renaming it root.crt because it doesn't accept such suffix) and give it the device.crt too ???

Comment: I've added root certificate to the root but didn't help , and the I don't know where to add device.crt !!!

Comment: @Igeorget plz just tell me where to add device.crt , this step is left .

Comment: The `device.crt` file is the certificate your server will check to verify that the device is actually an authorized device. It will be sent by the client to the server at the beginning of the connection. What kind of application do you need a client authentication for? If it is for web, you have to put your certificate in the list of certificates authenticating yourself. For example, in firefox, in the certificate view, there is a tab `your certificates`. What clientside application do you use?

Comment: thanks , I'm using firefox as a clientside and apache as web server