# Firefox error message when adding client certificate signed by CA

Tags: authentication, firefox, certificates

I'm getting this message when I'm trying to add a certificate to Firefox's "your certificate tab". I generated and signed it before by a server which also is a CA.

> Failed to decode the file.  Either it is not in PKCS #12 format, has
>   been corrupted, or the password you entered was incorrect.

It asks me to enter a password and then this message is alerted. what's wrong?
I'm following this [tutorial](http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/).

#### UPDATE #1

commands I used :

```
 openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048
 openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem       
 openssl genrsa -out device.key 2048     
 openssl req -new -key device.key -out device.csr       
 openssl x509 -req -in device.csr -CA rootCA.pem \
        -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out device.crt -days 500
```

The added certificate is device.crt, there's PKS12 which Firefox request on your certificates tab. Should I change its format?

Comment: We can hardly help you without seeing the certificate file you're trying to import, or without knowing **exactly** how you generated it (i.e. copy-paste the commands that **you** ran). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: They're in the tutorial :D , I'll put them now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1: Confirming type of certificate file

It sounds like the file you're trying to import is not in fact a .pk12 file. I would run this command to confirm the type of file you're importing:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in keyStore.p12
```

You should see something along these lines:

```
Enter Import Password:
MAC Iteration 2048
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 74 FF 2A 04 58 90 06 B5 A0 5C EF DA C0 9B 6C AD 91 BD 1F 54 
    friendlyName: [friendly name]
subject=/C=US/ST=NY/O=My Company/OU=dept/CN=blah.blah.com
issuer=/O=My Company/OU=dept/emailAddress=blah@blah.com/L=My Town/ST=NY/C=US/CN=blah.blah.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

!!!REMOVED CERTIFICATE!!!!

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=/O=My Company/OU=dept/emailAddress=blah@blah.com/L=My Town/ST=NY/C=US/CN=blah.blah.com
issuer=/O=My Company/OU=dept/emailAddress=blah@blah.com/L=My Town/ST=NY/C=US/CN=blah.blah.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

!!!REMOVED CERTIFICATE!!!

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 74 FF 2A 04 58 90 06 B5 A0 5C EF DA C0 9B 6C AD 91 BD 1F 54 
    friendlyName: [friendly name]
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

!!!REMOVED CERTIFICATE!!!

-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The OP ran the above command and got this error:

```
your command didn't work 
3077953260:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1320: 3077953260:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:382:Type=PKCS12
```

This error was telling the OP that the .crt file they had wasn't a pkcs12/pfx file.

At this point the OP shared another question: "[Failed to sign CSR with the CA root key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73836/)" they had asked related to this same issue.

After reading one of the comments the OP was in fact attempting to load a .crt file into a dialog within Firefox that was expecting a pkcs12/pfx formatted certificate. See below for how to convert a .crt to a pkcs12/pfx cert.

#### 2. Firefox "Your Certificates" Dialog

I found this question on the Firefox support forum titled: 
[Installing certificates in .crt format into "Your certificates"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/942794) that states as follows:

> I have a certificate in the .crt format which needs to be in the "Your
>   Certificates" tab.
>
> Firefox only allows certificates in the .p12 and .pfx formats there.
>
> How do I import this certificate into the "Your certificates" tab?
>
> I tried to see if I can convert .crt into .p12 but no luck. (the same
>   certificate I was able to convert to .p7b and .spc format)

Since it sounds like you have a .crt file you may be able to convert it to a pkcs12/pfx file using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.cer -inkey privateKey.key \
      -out certificate.pfx -certfile CACert.cer
```

**NOTE:** In that example CACert.cer would be the CA's .crt file. That command is mixing together your .crt file and the CA's .crt file into a pkcs12/pfx file.

The OP ran this command:

```
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -in certs/device.crt -inkey private/device.key -out safaa.pfx -certfile certs/myca.crt
```

### References

- [Setting up OpenSSL to Create Certificates](http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-openssl-create-certificates)
- [Creating PKCS12 Certificates - Flat Mountain](http://www.flatmtn.com/article/creating-pkcs12-certificates)

Comment: no , it's a signed crt . your command didn't work 
`
3077953260:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1320:
3077953260:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:382:Type=PKCS12`

Comment: I'm telling you that the file suffix is "crt" , check my question [here] , device.crt the file I'm giving to the browser , it's like my question is not clear , I don't know about p7b file you are talking about 
(http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73836/failed-to-sign-csr-with-the-ca-root-key)

Comment: ok , I'm still reading and trying , some links say that I have to make an openssl.cnf and edit it , some say that I have to work in etc/pki/ path , some say I have to edit apache configurations "ss.cnf" . a missing puzzle that I can't find because I'm not fully aware of the whole picture

Comment: what do mean by CACert.cer ? if certificate.cer stands for device.crt and privateKey.key stands for device.key , what's the third parameter in my case ?

Comment: `sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -in certs/device.crt -inkey private/device.key -out safaa.pfx -certfile certs/myca.crt`
It works , thanks

Comment: after making some edits in ssl.conf `

    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 2` I'm getting this [message](http://s10.postimg.org/3pw6xr509/Screenshot_from_2013_04_28_14_32_31.png) and after pressing ok [this message](http://s15.postimg.org/h5i0nekgr/Screenshot_from_2013_04_28_14_37_11.png) should I put another question ?

Comment: p.s : to prevent others from getting confused wen reading there comments  , myca.crt is rootCA.crt

Comment: [FirFox error](http://s1.postimg.org/g9zd6s5z3/Screenshot_from_2013_04_28_14_43_26.png)

Comment: Yes let's make that a 3rd question but when you ask it make sure to reference this question and the other one as part of it so you don't waste time re-reeducating potential answers this time 8-). Also I've moved some of the comments into my answer, if there is anything you can move up please do and delete from the comments section.

Comment: here's the third [episode](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73945/configuring-apache-to-require-a-client-certificate)