# Configuring Apache to Require a Client Certificate

Tags: authentication, apache-httpd, certificates

I want to implement mutual authentication (two - way ) with apache web server.

**References** : 
  1.[Failed to sign CSR with the CA root key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73836/failed-to-sign-csr-with-the-ca-root-key) 
  2.[Firefox error message when adding client certificate signed by CA](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73873/firefox-error-message-when-adding-client-certificate-signed-by-ca/73875?noredirect=1#comment107389_73875)

after many steps :

1. Configuring Apache 2.0 SSL to accept https by editing ssl.conf .
2. Creating a Certificate Authority using OpenSSL & importing it to the web browser [[link]](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/be-your-own-ca/)
3. Creating a Web Server Certificate  & sign it by CA & put it as apache certificate.[[link]](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/be-your-own-ca/)
4. Creating a Client Certificate & sign it by CA & export it as PKCS#12 format [[link]](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX106630)& import it to web browser

I now have an access with https to the server but for all users . 
I want just the authorized users who I gave them a signed certificate by CA to access to web pages on my server . I needed to edit ssl.conf in
    `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`
following this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20100312014427/http://www.cafesoft.com/products/cams/ps/docs30/admin/ConfiguringApache2ForSSLTLSMutualAuthentication.html) , I did this to ssl.conf :

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 2
```

**Update#1 :**

and of course I had set the certificate to the signed one by CA :

```
#   Server Certificate:
#SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/sslConf/server.crt
#   Server Private Key:
#SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/sslConf/server.key
```

and as a result I got this [message](http://s10.postimg.org/3pw6xr509/Screenshot_from_2013_04_28_14_32_31.png) and after pressing ok this [message](http://s15.postimg.org/h5i0nekgr/Screenshot_from_2013_04_28_14_37_11.png)  ([in firefox](http://s1.postimg.org/g9zd6s5z3/Screenshot_from_2013_04_28_14_43_26.png)). 
what's the mistake I had committed ?

Comment: I'd go through this tutorial and see what steps you're either missing or differ: http://linuxconfig.org/apache-web-server-ssl-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the Apache logs to see what is wrong. It looks like apache isn't able to verify the client certificate.

Do you have the SSLCACertificateFile directive set correctly? This is necessarry, apache cannot verify certificate otherwise.

Comment: yes , you are right , I forget to set it :D , it gave me the same massage and not it's https correctly :)